# How to sort list in javascripts as Alpha then numeric?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to sort a list of sele ctions values as alphabets order fallowed by Numerical characters when i do default sort numeric values come on top then alphabetical order i want list as alphaticals then numberics

```js
function add() {
  var frm = document.getElementById('formAdmin');
  var selectedChnls = frm.selectedAssignedChnlOrgList;
  var activChnls = frm.activeChnl;
  var inactivChnls = frm.inactiveChnl;

  var activeAssignedChnlOrgList = frm.activeAssignedChnlOrgList

  for (i = 0; i < activChnls.length; i++) {
    if (activChnls[i].selected == true) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = activChnls[i].value;
      opt.innerHTML = activChnls[i].label;
      activChnls[i].disabled = true;
      activChnls[i].selected = false;
      selectedChnls.appendChild(opt);
    }
  }
  sortSelect();
}

function sortSelect() {
  let frm = document.getElementById('formAdmin');
  let selElem = frm.selectedAssignedChnlOrgList;
  let tmpAry = new Array();
  for (let i = 0; i < selElem.options.length; i++) {
    tmpAry[i] = new Array();
    tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
    tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
  }
  tmpAry.sort();
  while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
    selElem.options[0] = null;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < tmpAry.length; i++) {
    let op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
    selElem.options[i] = op;
  }
  return;
}
```

```html
<form name="adminForm" id="formAdmin" method="post" action="http://localhost:7003/ccrSrc/initAdmin.do">
  <table style="margin-top: -15px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="760">
    <tbody>
      <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
        <td width="800" valign="top" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
          <table class="orgtable">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="tabletitle2" width="40%" nowrap="">Available Orgs:</td>
                <td class="tabletitle2" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="tabletitle2" width="40%" nowrap="">Assigned Orgs:</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <!--Available Organizations-->
                <td width="40%" class="bodytext6">
                  <div id="Status1" style="cursor:default; display: inline;">
                    <select id="" name="activeChnl" multiple="multiple" size="25%" style="overflow-x:scroll;width:100%">
                      <option value="1">Accountancy, Banking and Finance</option>
                      <option value="2">Animal and Plant Resource</option>
                      <option value="3">Business, Consulting and Management</option>
                      <option value="4">Charity and Voluntary Work</option>
                      <option value="5">Creative Arts and Design</option>
                      <option value="6">Energy and Utilities</option>
                      <option value="7">Engineering and Manufacturing</option>
                      <option value="8">Enviromemt amd Agriculture</option>
                      <option value="9">Healthcare</option>
                      <option value="10">Hospitality and Events Management</option>
                      <option value="1000013677">4L Accountancy, Banking and Finance</option>
                      <option value="1000012499">1763615 Creative Arts and Design</option>
                      <option value="1000015252">2540722 Energy and Utilities</option>
                      <option value="1000013677">1863615 Healthcare</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </td>

                <td align="center" width="20%" class="tabletitle2" nowrap="">
                  <br><br><br><br>
                  <a id="btnAdd" type="button" style="font-size:20" onclick="javascript:add();">Add >></a><br><br><br>
                </td>

                <td width="40%" class="bodytext6">
                  <select name="selectedAssignedChnlOrgList" multiple="multiple" size="25%" style="overflow-x:scroll;width:100%"></select>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                  <button id="cancel" style="width:75px;" type="button" onclick="javascript:loadUserOrgAction();">Cancel</button>
                  <button id="save" style="width:75px;" type="button" onclick="javascript:loadUserOrgAction();">Save</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

i want same order when it added on right side of the page as alphabetical order first then numerics after all alphabetics

Answer (score 0):

this way :
*any question(s) ?*

```js
const 
  adminForm   = document.forms['adminForm']
, arrActiv    = Array.from( adminForm.activeChnl.options )
, arrAssigned = []
  ;
adminForm.btnAdd.onclick = () =>
  {
  Array.from( adminForm.activeChnl.selectedOptions ).forEach( opt => 
    {
    let 
      key = arrActiv.findIndex( el => el===opt ) // get original option index
    , elm = opt.cloneNode(true)                  // clone option
      ;
    opt.disabled = true
    arrAssigned.push({ key,elm })
    })

  if (adminForm.activeChnl.selectedOptions.length > 0 )
    {
    adminForm.activeChnl.selectedIndex = -1 // unselect anything

    arrAssigned.sort((a,b)=>parseInt(a.key)-parseInt(b.key) ) // sort

    arrAssigned.forEach( row => // reorganize the select 2 order
      {
      adminForm.selectedAssignedChnlOrgList.appendChild( row.elm )  // what a name!
      })
    }
  }
```

```css
select {
  height : 30em;
  width  : 22em;
}
```

```html
<form name="adminForm">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="activeChnl" multiple >
            <option value="1">Accountancy, Banking and Finance</option>
            <option value="2">Animal and Plant Resource</option>
            <option value="3">Business, Consulting and Management</option>
            <option value="4">Charity and Voluntary Work</option>
            <option value="5">Creative Arts and Design</option>
            <option value="6">Energy and Utilities</option>
            <option value="7">Engineering and Manufacturing</option>
            <option value="8">Enviromemt amd Agriculture</option>
            <option value="9">Healthcare</option>
            <option value="10">Hospitality and Events Management</option>
            <option value="1000013677">4L Accountancy, Banking and Finance</option>
            <option value="1000012499">1763615 Creative Arts and Design</option>
            <option value="1000015252">2540722 Energy and Utilities</option>
            <option value="1000013677">1863615 Healthcare</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td> <button name="btnAdd" type="button">Add</button> </td>
        <td>
          <select name="selectedAssignedChnlOrgList" multiple >
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to sort by value:

```js
function sortSelect() {
  let frm = document.getElementById('formAdmin');
  let selElem = frm.selectedAssignedChnlOrgList;
  let tmpAry = new Array();
  for (let i = 0; i < selElem.options.length; i++) {
    tmpAry[i] = new Array();
    tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
    tmpAry[i][1] = parseInt(selElem.options[i].value);  
  }
  tmpAry.sort(compareByValue);
  
  while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
    selElem.options[0] = null;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < tmpAry.length; i++) {
    let op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
    selElem.options[i] = op;
  }
  
 function compareByValue(a, b) {
   return a[1] - b[1];    
}
  return;
}
```

Comment: i want to sort by label not with value